# set AsyncCompletedEventHandler to method outside of class

Tags: c#, .net

I apologize in advance if my question is worded poorly.

I am utilizing `WebClient` to download a file from the internet. To set the `DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler` to a method in the same class, I simply use the method name, e.g.

```
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged +=
    new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressReporter);
```

How do I go about setting the `DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler` to a method outside of the class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If that method is static, prefix it with the name of the class it is defined in:

```
class ClassWithStaticMethod
{
    public static void ProgressReporter(object s,
                                        DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Used like:

```
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += ClassWithStaticMethod.ProgressReporter;
```

If it is an instance method, you need to have an instance of that class in hand:

```
class ClassWithInstanceMethod
{
    public void ProgressReporter(object s, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Used like:

```
var myObject = new ClassWithInstanceMethod();
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += myObject.ProgressReporter;
```

Finally, note that you do not need to use `new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler` when subscribing to the event because the compiler can deduce it automatically.

Comment: I see, thank you. I should have added this to my question:
What if it is unknown until runtime which method I want to use as the event handler? e.g. the webClient class has a method that allows the user to set any method as the event handler...

Comment: @JeffDavis - consider updating your question or starting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += someOtherClassInstance.ProgressReporter
```

Comment: Notice that the compiler implicitly creates a delegate around your method, so wrapping with `new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressReporter)` is really only introducing noise.

Answer (score 0):

If your external event handler is in a class called foo and the handler is static, you would pass foo.ProgressReport instead of ProgressReport.

```
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(foo.ProgressReport);
```

If it is not static, then you need an instance of foo.

```
Foo myFoo = new Foo();
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(myFoo.ProgressReport);
```